# Edittext in mathview

Tags: android, android-layout, calculator

I'm trying to develop a scientific calculator using Mathview. But I'm unable to edit the Mathview. How can i put Editext in the Mathview like in the following image?

[image]

Mathview library- https://github.com/kexanie/MathView

Comment: can you please specify link of mathview library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not Edit the MathView with that library as per I know. As there are no proper Android libraries to display math, your requirement will be achieved if you are moving to jQuery and javascript by using webView. for reference, please visit: [MathSolver](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thirdleap.mathsjunior)